# How to accept Paypal donations on iPhone iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, paypal, ios5

I am developing an application where a user needs to donate money using his Paypal account for charity cause.
I have gone through the Paypal website, but I haven't found any specific API to implement it on an iPhone.

I have explored a lot, but I was not able to find any satisfactory answer.

Comment: Dude! Accept the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_documentation

then scroll down to PayPal Mobile (about 2/3's of the way down)

https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_MPL_Developer_Guide_and_Reference_iPhone.pdf

This manual is 58 pages long and has tons of great details.

If it's too technical you might need to outsource it, i.e. pay.

Comment: Why is this document so hard to find?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check and see whether Apple is accepting or rejecting iOS apps that claim to accept PayPal donations for charity.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out this comparisons for API.

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/mobile-overview

MPL is the easiest to integrate but will require a paypal account from the user. MECL is a bit tricky but shouldn't be that far off. Plus it gives the user the option to use credit cards.

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/mobile-express-checkout-library

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/mobile-payment-libraries

Both APIs will require you to submit to paypal first for review in order to get an API key for the app.

Answer (score 0):

Apple will likely reject apps with a donate button taking you to PayPal.

You could implement in-app purchase to remove ads or something. That takes you to Apple's App store, which Apple does allow Or put a donate button on your web site, not on the app.